# Rendering failed after variable changes name

Tags: html, go, go-templates

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75713085/golang-post-failed-nosurf-csrf), I have some Golang code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R5Vbqk8YIw4cGKZWGJrsnRAPR-0lupg4/view?usp=share_link).  Currently, the `localhost:8080/search-availability` renders properly.  Its content is as follows:

[image: img]

If I were to change line 13 of `templates\search-availability.page.tmpl`:

```
<input type="text" name="csrf_token" value="{{.CsrfToken}}">
```

into:

```
<input type="text" name="csrf_token" value="{{.WrongToken}}">
```

anything below `Search for Availability` will disappear.

To debug the issue mentioned in the other question, I want to do a rename in `pkg\models\templatedata.go`:

```
type TemplateData struct {
    StringMap map[string]string
    IntMap    map[string]int
    FloatMap  map[string]float64
    Data      map[string]interface{}
    // CsrfToken string
    Token string
    Flash     string
    Error     string
}
```

Basically, `CsrfToken` gets shortened into `Token`.  To accommodate the change, line 13 of `templates\search-availability.page.tmpl` is changed into:

```
<!-- <input type="text" name="csrf_token" value="{{.CsrfToken}}"> -->
<input type="text" name="csrf_token" value="{{.Token}}">
```

(I only comment out the old value.  This will be clear later.)  Accordingly, `pkg\render\render.go` has this change:

```
func AddDefaultData(td *models.TemplateData, r *http.Request) *models.TemplateData {
    // td.CsrfToken = nosurf.Token(r)
    fmt.Printf("Token before: %s\n", td.Token)
    td.Token = nosurf.Token(r)
    fmt.Printf("Token after: %s\n", td.Token)
    return td
}
```

Then I run `go run ./cmd/web/*.go` to see if it works.  Surprisingly, everything below `Search for Availability` is missing.  This is the output from the terminal:

```
Starting a server on port :8080
2023/03/12 23:54:46 SessionLoad
2023/03/12 23:54:46 NoSurf
2023/03/12 23:54:47 Hit the page
2023/03/12 23:54:47 Availability
Token before: 
Token after: ERyPRtSgyVxmtthfMD49BsysXczubQfn7SQ3+L0ntc+6PQoHlaykAYejIa6Vw4m4omkgO94tVi/YiD0baSz2yw==
```

`VS Code` code complete can pick up `td.Token` and the terminal shows that that variable exists.  Why is it behaving just like when `WrongToken` is used?  Removing both of these lines brings back the content from `Arrival` and after:

```
<!-- <input type="text" name="csrf_token" value="{{.CsrfToken}}"> -->
<input type="text" name="csrf_token" value="{{.Token}}">
```

I am at a loss here. Why is this happening?  Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your structure does not have a `WrongToken` field. If you commented out `CsrfToken`, then the structure no longer has that either. Commenting out the HTML template does not remove it from the output, your template is still looking for `CsrfToken` variable.

Comment: Please consider handling errors instead of ignoring them. The standard template's `Execute` methods return an `error` if they encounter an issue like a missing struct field.

Answer (score 0):

Template expressions within HTML comments are still evaluated. The presence of a non-existent field will cause `Execute()` to stop and return an error.

Alternatively, you can use a template comment (see the first entry in [the list of actions in the text/template documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Actions)). This will cause the enclosed content to be discarded when executing the template.

Here's a small example to illustrate:

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    const validTpl = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>example page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        A field: {{.Field}}<br>
        A non-existent field within a template comment: {{/* {{.NonExistenField}} within a template comment */}}
        A non-existent field within an HTML comment: <!-- {{.NonExistentField}} -->
    </body>
</html>`

    t, err := template.New("webpage").Parse(validTpl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data := struct {
        Field string
    }{
        Field: "data",
    }

    err = t.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>example page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        A field: data<br>
        A non-existent field within a template comment: 
        A non-existent field within an HTML comment: 2009/11/10 23:00:00 template: webpage:11:54: executing "webpage" at <.NonExistentField>: can't evaluate field NonExistentField in type struct { Field string }

Program exited.
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/KBCLO1tWT_p)